# Interest Rate and Present Value Question

Tags: interest-rate, interest

I'm trying to answer the hypothetical question posted below (for educational purposes) but I'm very confused about its wording regarding the interest rate.  If I assume that the interest is compounded monthly (I'm guessing this is what the question is trying to state), I obtain that the value of $1 today is equivalent to $1.05^3 three months from now, hence the present value of the stock is $37/1.05^3 and so the quoted price for two months from now is going to be $37/1.05 multiplying through by 1.05^2.  Is this the correct interpretation?  I'm just lost in terminology, obviously this isn't even a math question really.

[image]

Comment: What does the textbook say about similar problems in that chapter?

Comment: There is no mention about what "compounding for longer periods" means.  Is my calculation correct based on the interpretation I give?